# Why do certain types of sound seem to fade faster?

Tags: acoustics

I noticed that if I'm playing music in a room and I go into another room or walk further and further, then at some point I can only hear the percussion and the melody to a lesser extent. All the midtones seem to vanish. Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do low frequency sounds really carry longer distances?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87751/)

Comment: Do you mean all the middle frequencies fade, you can still hear both the highest and lowest notes? Sorry, not well up on music enough to completely follow your question?